# Can't Install Cordova

Tags: cordova

Hello I can't install cordova from npm can someone help me please thank you.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'cordova' ]
2 info using npm@2.5.1
3 info using node@v0.12.0
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 silly cache add args [ 'cordova', null ]
6 verbose cache add spec cordova
7 silly cache add parsed spec { raw: 'cordova',
7 silly cache add   scope: null,
7 silly cache add   name: null,
7 silly cache add   rawSpec: 'cordova',
7 silly cache add   spec: 'C:\\Users\\SarahPrat\\cordova',
7 silly cache add   type: 'local' }
8 silly addLocalTarball shasum (computed) da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
9 verbose addTmpTarball C:\Users\SarahPrat\cordova not in flight; adding
10 verbose addTmpTarball validating metadata from C:\Users\SarahPrat\cordova
11 verbose tar unpack C:\Users\SarahPrat\cordova
12 verbose tar unpacking to C:\Users\SARAHP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-6544-89c7caba\unpack-5a50cbddcae0
13 verbose gentlyRm vacuuming C:\Users\SARAHP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-6544-89c7caba\unpack-5a50cbddcae0
14 silly gunzTarPerm modes [ '777', '666' ]
15 error tar.unpack error reading C:\Users\SarahPrat\cordova
16 error addLocal Could not install C:\Users\SarahPrat\cordova
17 verbose stack Error: 0-byte tarball
17 verbose stack Please run `npm cache clean`
17 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\tar.js:126:14
17 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:99:15)
18 verbose cwd C:\Users\SarahPrat
19 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
20 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
21 error node v0.12.0
22 error npm  v2.5.1
23 error 0-byte tarball
23 error Please run `npm cache clean`
24 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
24 error     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice will be to not bother with all the command line stuff. You can install Eclipse Thym(The hybride Mobile) plugin in Eclipse and add every cordova plugin you want in Eclipse by left click on project-> Install cordova plugin.

It works well for me, hope it helps

You can install Eclipse Thym in Eclipse with Help->Eclipse Marketplace->type Eclipse thym

However if you don't want to do this , to use npm you must install Node first : https://nodejs.org/

Finally, here is a get started tutorial :

http://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/create-cordova-project.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for your problem based on your error message.

Run as Administrator your CMD. Second maybe you not install node.js. https://nodejs.org/